# Steps to create new faces between 2 selected meshes?

Tags: edges, faces

I have a model of a sword. In the original model, the surfaces of the flat sides of the blade are flat. I'm working to inset the surfaces a little bit to provide some depth.

I've separated the the model into 3 meshes, 2 for the flat parts and the third being the rest of the sword.

Now I'm trying to figure out how to join the meshes so that they create new vertical faces along the edges, but I'm not really sure how to do that. This will let me move the flat surface meshes back into place but inset a few millimeters.

Hopefully the attached screenshot will be fairly clear. I've selected the two edges that I'm trying to join.

[image]

After applying "Bridge Edge Loops":

[image]

Comment: Do you mean something like "bridge edge loops"?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Had to look that up and it does seem to be close to the right direction. However I'm getting some weird new geometry from that. I'm attaching a new screenshot after applying bridge edge loops for you to see.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I'm guessing here, but I suspect the bridge problems may arise because the two meshes don't have equal edge counts. Sound right?

Comment: It's quite possible that's the case, but I'm not sure. There's a lot going on in that photo, it's kind of hard to tell. Any chance you could upload a .blend file?

Comment: Try tweaking the *Twist* factor when you use *bridge edge loops* (expand the panel in the lower left of the viewport right after using the operator)